# In Excel 2011 the "date" function doesn't show the 4 digit year - can anyone explain why this happens

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

When I use the following, I get:

- `MsgBox(date)` - 01/04/
- `?date` in the immediate window, the same - 01/04/
- `?year(date)` - 2015
- `?now` - 01/04/ 07:18:19

I'm confused. My Macbook Pro is set to English and would display as 01/04/2015. I can't see any settings in Excel that would cause this.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you share the VBA you have for the `MsgBox`?

Comment: Simply running this code will do it:
    Sub DisplayDate()
       MsgBox Date
    End Sub
If I run this on Excel 2010 it displays "01/04/2014"
If I run this on Excel 2011 it displays "01/04/"

Answer (score 0):

Right click the cell, choose format cells. Select date, and choose how you wish to format the date.

Excel tries to automate formatting the cell as it sees fit. Format Cells overrides that per cell.

Comment: Cell formatting isn't the issue.
If I use vba to assign the "date" function to a cell it displays correctly:
(01/04/15).
However, when I try and display it with MsgBox (or Immediate Window) is when I see the problem.

Comment: Yeah, thats normal behavior. If you want to display it in a messagebox whitin vba, format the date there.